# How can I get images and environment variables from GKE(GCP) using cloud function(python)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to get images and environment variables from GKE cluster using python. I`ve already seen the python container library for gcp, but it seems like there is no such logic as I need https://github.com/googleapis/python-container, https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/libraries#create-service-account-gcloud. This lib can help with getting clusters, but I cannot see something about cluster-info.

Is my task possible with this lib? Or, if not please advice something.

What I need to do? To create the cloud function that will get parameters such as cluster, zone or something(don`t know now) and return the images, environment variables and maybe something else in response.

Please provide the sample or some useful links to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google Cloud client libraries to interact with Google Cloud services, for instance GKE, Cloud Functions or other GCP product.

If you want to interact with Kubernetes itself (hosted on GKE or elsewhere, but what you want is to read the control plane configuration to get pod/container configuration and env vars), you have to query Kubernetes itself on the control plane IP that provide the client libraries.

Comment: I think I need to read configuration, you said, that I need query GKE, could you please provide more information about it?

Comment: Have on look on thie: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python